# Celery and transaction.atomic

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions, celery

In some Django views, I used a pattern like this to save changes to a model, and then to do some asynchronous updating (such as generating images, further altering the model) based on the new model data.  `mytask` is a celery task:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    mymodel.save()
    mytask.delay(mymodel.id).get()
```

The problem is that the task never returns.  Looking at celery's logs, the task gets queued (I see "Received task" in the log), but it never completes.  If I move the `mytask.delay...get` call out of the transaction, it completes successfully.

Is there some incompatibility between `transaction.atomic` and celery?  Is it possible in Django 1.6 or 1.7 for me to have both regular model updates and updates from a separate task process under one transaction?

My database is postgresql 9.1.  I'm using celery==3.1.16 / django-celery 3.1.16, amqp==1.4.6, Django==1.6.7, kombu==3.0.23.  The broker backend is amqp, and rabitmq as the queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Separate task" = something that is ran by a worker.

"Celery worker" = another process.

I am not aware of any method that would let you have a single database transaction shared between 2 or more processess. What you want is to run the task in a synchronous way, in that transaction, and wait for the result... but, if that's what you want, why do you need a task queue anyway?

Comment: Well, on Windows the DTC supports it.

Comment: Why I need the task queue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7543682/85461. Because of an esoteric problem with OS signals from java subprocesses interacting with WSGI, it can be necessary to use a separate process sometimes even when you need a synchronous result.

Answer (score 44):

As [@dotz mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31030040/2263517), it is hardly useful to spawn an async task and immediately block and keep waiting until it finishes.

Moreover, if you attach to it this way (the `.get()` at the end), you can be sure that the `mymodel` instance changes just made won't be seen by your worker because they won't be committed yet - remember you're still inside the `atomic` block.

What you could do instead (from Django 1.9) is delay the task until after the current active transaction is committed, using `django.db.transaction.on_commit` hook:

```
from django.db import transaction

with transaction.atomic():
    mymodel.save()
    transaction.on_commit(lambda:
        mytask.delay(mymodel.id))
```

I use this pattern quite often in my `post_save` signal handlers that trigger some processing of new model instances. For example:

```
from django.db import transaction
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . import models   # Your models defining some Order model
from . import tasks   # Your tasks defining a routine to process new instances

@receiver(post_save, sender=models.Order)
def new_order_callback(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    """ Automatically triggers processing of a new Order. """
    if created:
        transaction.on_commit(lambda:
            tasks.process_new_order.delay(instance.pk))
```

This way, however, your task **won't be executed** if the database transaction fails. It is usually the desired behavior, but keep it in mind.

**Edit**: It's actually nicer to register the on_commit celery task this way (w/o lambda):

```
transaction.on_commit(tasks.process_new_order.s(instance.pk).delay)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for Celery signature. For some reason syntax with lambda is producing incorrect behaviour - Celery runs tasks with wrong arguments (doubles same one).

Comment: Lambdas work fine for me, but this `.s` pattern is a lot cleaner! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are some race conditions in Celery tasks. 
I think [here](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#database-transactions) is an explanation of your problem.

Take a look into those docs. Also there are some packages like [django-celery-transactions](https://github.com/bradleyayers/django-celery-transactions) that can help you with your question.

Comment: Thanks -- those docs do point to a potential source of the problem. ``django-celery-transactions`` looks good if I want to skip the async task if the regular model update raises an exception -- but I'm looking for a way to rollback the whole transaction if the async task fails.  As far as I can tell, ``django-celery-transactions`` leaves the work in the task to a separate transaction.