# How to ensure Django model saves before Celery task execution?

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a Django 1.11 + MySQL + Celery 4.1 project where a view creates a new user record, and then kicks off a Celery task to perform additional long-running actions in relation to it.

The typical problem in this case is ensuring that the user creation is committed to the database before the Celery task executes. Otherwise, there's a race condition, and the task may try and access a record that doesn't exit if it executes before the transaction commits.

The way I had learned to fix this was to always wrap the record creation in a manual transaction or atomic block, and then trigger the Celery task after that. e.g.

```
def create_user():
    with transaction.atomic():
        user = User.objects.create(username='blah')
    mytask.apply_async(args=[user.id])

@task
def mytask(user_id):
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    do_stuff(user)
```

However, I still occasionally see the error `DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist` in my Celery worker logs, implying my task is sometimes executing before the user record gets committed.

Is this not the correct strategy or am I not implementing it correctly?

Comment: It looks like you need to use an `on_commit` hook with your transacation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.on_commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery and transaction.atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942604/celery-and-transaction-atomic)

Answer (score 0):

I believe a `post_save` signal would be more appropriate for what you're trying to do: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save. This signal sends a `created` argument as a boolean, making it easy to operate only on object creation.