# Celery signatures .s(): early or late binding?

Tags: python, django, celery, late-binding, early-binding

This [blog post](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/08/22/use-partial-with-djangos-transaction-on-commit/) of Adam Johnson perfectly illustrates the difference between ***early binding*** and ***late binding*** closures in Python. This is also explained [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures).

I've got a function `my_func` which corresponds to a Celery task (it's decorated with `@shared_task`). It expects some arguments. I run it with the following piece of code, using Celery signatures as described [in the documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#signatures) (see also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942604/celery-and-transaction-atomic#answer-40050417)):

```py
from functools import partial
from django.db import transaction
from example.tasks import my_func

# next line can be found at the end of some other functions which involve a transaction
transaction.on_commit(my_func.s(param1, param2).delay))
```

**Are Celery signatures early binding or late binding?**
And how to demonstrate it in an elegant way?

If they are early binding, the following line of code should be equivalent:

```py
transaction.on_commit(partial(my_func.delay, param1, param2))
```

If they are late binding, I think I could be facing a pesky bug with my current code, in some edge cases...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, according to your link, [in this section](https://adamj.eu/tech/2022/08/22/use-partial-with-djangos-transaction-on-commit/#partial-prevents-a-pesky-bug):

> `partial()` is early binding, whilst all the prior techniques are late
> binding.
>
> Early binding here means that function arguments are resolved when
> calling `partial()`

At the risk of being pedantic, I would say that this is mixing terminology. Late/early binding applies to *how **free variables** are evaluated when a function that creates a closures is called*.

When you are talking about *how **arguments** are evaluated during a function call*, that's different. For all function calls in python the arguments are evaluated fully *when the function is called*. That is a consequence of Python's evaluation strategy, which is strict (also called greedy) as opposed to non-strict (also called lazy).

The strict/greed evaluation of function arguments is analogous to early-binding in closures. So using this way of phrasing it, yes, `.s` is "early binding".

That is, because `my_func.s(param1, param2)` is *just a function call*, then the arguments are eagerly evaluated.

---

Note, one example of a non-strict evaluation strategy is call-by-name. Languages like [scala](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/by-name-parameters.html) for an example) support call by name.

There is also Haskell, which has call-by-need, which is like a cached version fo call-by-name. Because Haskell is purely functional, and doesn't *allow* variables to be re-assigned, you don't see bugs like the ones you would be worried about though.