# populating PDF form with Excel data

Tags: python, excel, forms, pdf

I have an Excel spread sheet e.g.:

```
Patent No.   Issue Date    Patentee
7,777,776    2010-08-17    Horiuchi
7,777,778    2010-08-17    Scharenbroch, et al.
```

I want to use this data to fill in the following form:
https://www.uspto.gov/sites/default/files/patents/process/file/efs/guidance/updated_IDS.pdf

Note that there is an add button on the PDF form to create a second row in the PDF for the data from the second row from the spreadsheet.

I am familiar with Python, but the similar solutions I have seen either create new form from scratch ([How can I auto-populate a PDF form in Django/Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890570/how-can-i-auto-populate-a-pdf-form-in-django-python)) or do not manipulate the add button in the PDF form ([Batch fill PDF forms from python or bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476265/batch-fill-pdf-forms-from-python-or-bash)).