# Python Advice for Project: Taking input and writing to existing PDF?? WebApp?

Tags: python, pdf, web-applications

I am somewhat of a beginner at Python and I am currently starting some brainstorming and planning for a project to simplify the tedious task of filling out a product order form for a friend's business. I am wanting to create a program with an interface that takes in input and writes to an already existing pdf form of the physical order form. I would also like to implement being able to then email that form to another coworker and having accessible information of previous orders from the current customer ordering.

I am most curious about how to write to an already existing pdf form and just fill in the blanks, potentially using a PDF Reader? Also, for product catalog data and customer order history, would using dictionaries suffice or would it be better to use some python database?

I know I could figure out how to individually do each of those tasks but I don't know how to tie it all together properly to distribute it, either making a WebApp or an executable file from the script and just use tkinter or another GUI library for the interface, or if there is a more obvious and convenient option?

If I were to do a WebApp, what would be my best option, I've seen options such as Anvil, Flask, Django, and I just don't know what would be best for what I'm trying to accomplish.

I know this is a longshot and vague but any advice or guidance in the right direction would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hey there - welcome to SO! This site is for people with [minimal, reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with an _expected output_ and to tell us what _is not_ working. Perhaps there is another site listed on [StackExchange](https://stackexchange.com/sites) that can help you! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with a web app here. Personally, I prefer [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), and I don't think that it would be too difficult to learn it well enough for your purposes!

Regarding saving product catalog data and customer order history: I would definitely recommend using a database for your backend, which [Django helps you do](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/databases/)! Database integration is almost ridiculously easy using Django.

Here's some resources for the specific things you asked about:

- [Django vs. Flask](https://testdriven.io/blog/django-vs-flask/)
- [Working with HTML forms (Django)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) (this will help with taking user input)
- [filling an existing PDF form in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476265/batch-fill-pdf-forms-from-python-or-bash) (this will help with using user input to fill out the pdfs)
- [How to send email attachments in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362600/how-to-send-email-attachments) (this will help you email your coworker the filled out pdf)

If you need more help/guidance, definitely feel free to follow up!