# Can I use Python to fill form fields in a PDF document?

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

I have a form field fillable PDF that I'd like to fill using a python script, I can't use JavaScript which seems to be the preferred solution. Is this something that can be done through a python script? The catch is that I can't install any libraries like PyPDF2, fillpdf, or fdfgen like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476265/batch-fill-pdf-forms-from-python-or-bash) answer. Is this still possible? Can I homebrew a similar solution?

The fields can be tabbed through and assuming the alt text of a field is its name, I have those as well, though at least 1 field appears to be unnamed.

Ideally I'd like to fill multiple specific fields with variables that I can programmatically generate and then save the PDF as a new file.

Comment: These answers use fdfgen, which I can't get.

Comment: Can you install an arbitrary binary to accomplish this? I know a non-Python solution, it's freemium and requires cloud access.