# pdf form filled with PyPDF2 does not show in print

Tags: python-3.x, pdf-form, pypdf

I need to fill pdf form in batch, so tried to write a python code to do it for me from a csv file. I used second answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10476265/batch-fill-pdf-forms-from-python-or-bash) and it fills the forms fine, however when I open the filled forms the answers does not show unless the corresponding field is selected. Also the answers does not show when the form is printed. I looked into PyPDF2 documents to see if I can flatten the generated forms but this features has not been implemented yet even though has been asked for about a year ago. My preference is not to use pdftk so I can compile the script without the need for more dependency. When using the original code in the mentioned question, some fields show in the print and some doesn't which makes me confused on how they're working. Any help is appreciated.

Here's the code.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from collections import OrderedDict
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileWriter, PdfFileReader


def _getFields(obj, tree=None, retval=None, fileobj=None):
    """
    Extracts field data if this PDF contains interactive form fields.
    The *tree* and *retval* parameters are for recursive use.

    :param fileobj: A file object (usually a text file) to write
    a report to on all interactive form fields found.
    :return: A dictionary where each key is a field name, and each
    value is a :class:`Field<PyPDF2.generic.Field>` object. By
    default, the mapping name is used for keys.
    :rtype: dict, or ``None`` if form data could not be located.
    """
    fieldAttributes = {'/FT': 'Field Type', '/Parent': 'Parent', '/T': 'Field Name', '/TU': 'Alternate Field Name',
                   '/TM': 'Mapping Name', '/Ff': 'Field Flags', '/V': 'Value', '/DV': 'Default Value'}
    if retval is None:
        retval = {} #OrderedDict()
        catalog = obj.trailer["/Root"]
        # get the AcroForm tree
        if "/AcroForm" in catalog:
            tree = catalog["/AcroForm"]
        else:
            return None
    if tree is None:
        return retval

    obj._checkKids(tree, retval, fileobj)
    for attr in fieldAttributes:
        if attr in tree:
            # Tree is a field
            obj._buildField(tree, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)
            break

    if "/Fields" in tree:
        fields = tree["/Fields"]
        for f in fields:
            field = f.getObject()
            obj._buildField(field, retval, fileobj, fieldAttributes)

    return retval


def get_form_fields(infile):
    infile = PdfFileReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    fields = _getFields(infile)
    return {k: v.get('/V', '') for k, v in fields.items()}


def update_form_values(infile, outfile, newvals=None):
    pdf = PdfFileReader(open(infile, 'rb'))
    writer = PdfFileWriter()

    for i in range(pdf.getNumPages()):
        page = pdf.getPage(i)
        try:
            if newvals:
                writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(page, newvals)
            else:
                writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(page,
                                             {k: f'#{i} {k}={v}'
                                              for i, (k, v) in 
enumerate(get_form_fields(infile).items())
                                              })
            writer.addPage(page)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
            writer.addPage(page)

    with open(outfile, 'wb') as out:
        writer.write(out)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import csv    
    import os
    from glob import glob
    cwd=os.getcwd()
    outdir=os.path.join(cwd,'output')
    csv_file_name=os.path.join(cwd,'formData.csv')
    pdf_file_name=glob(os.path.join(cwd,'*.pdf'))[0]
    if not pdf_file_name:
        print('No pdf file found')
    if not os.path.isdir(outdir):
        os.mkdir(outdir)
    if not os.path.isfile(csv_file_name):
        fields=get_form_fields(pdf_file_name)
        with open(csv_file_name,'w',newline='') as csv_file:
            csvwriter=csv.writer(csv_file,delimiter=',')
            csvwriter.writerow(['user label'])
            csvwriter.writerow(['fields']+list(fields.keys()))
            csvwriter.writerow(['Mr. X']+list(fields.values()))
    else:
        with open(csv_file_name,'r',newline='') as csv_file:
            csvreader=csv.reader(csv_file,delimiter=',')
            csvdata=list(csvreader)
        fields=csvdata[1][1:]
        for frmi in csvdata[2:]:
            frmdict=dict(zip(fields,frmi[1:]))
            outfile=os.path.join(outdir,frmi[0]+'.pdf')
            update_form_values(pdf_file_name, outfile,frmdict)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue and apparently adding the "/NeedsAppearance" attribute to the PdfWriter object of the AcroForm fixed the problem (see https://github.com/mstamy2/PyPDF2/issues/355). With much help from ademidun (https://github.com/ademidun), I was able to populate a pdf form and have the values of the fields show properly. The following is an example:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter
from PyPDF2.generic import BooleanObject, NameObject, IndirectObject


def set_need_appearances_writer(writer):
    # See 12.7.2 and 7.7.2 for more information:
    # http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/acrobat/
    #     pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf
    try:
        catalog = writer._root_object
        # get the AcroForm tree and add "/NeedAppearances attribute
        if "/AcroForm" not in catalog:
            writer._root_object.update(
                {
                    NameObject("/AcroForm"): IndirectObject(
                        len(writer._objects), 0, writer
                    )
                }
            )

        need_appearances = NameObject("/NeedAppearances")
        writer._root_object["/AcroForm"][need_appearances] = BooleanObject(True)
        return writer

    except Exception as e:
        print("set_need_appearances_writer() catch : ", repr(e))
        return writer


reader = PdfFileReader("myInputPdf.pdf", strict=False)
if "/AcroForm" in reader.trailer["/Root"]:
    reader.trailer["/Root"]["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)}
    )

writer = PdfFileWriter()
set_need_appearances_writer(writer)
if "/AcroForm" in writer._root_object:
    writer._root_object["/AcroForm"].update(
        {NameObject("/NeedAppearances"): BooleanObject(True)}
    )

field_dictionary = {"Field1": "Value1", "Field2": "Value2"}

writer.addPage(reader.getPage(0))
writer.updatePageFormFieldValues(writer.getPage(0), field_dictionary)

with open("myOutputPdf.pdf", "wb") as fp:
    writer.write(fp)
```

Comment: This works great. thanks. Just as a general practice, always close a file after you open it :-)

Comment: Nice @tromar. I wonder if you could propose a mod for me? I'd like to replace inputstream with a byte(or string?) stream. Effectively, I am loading infile in your code from a PostgreSQL bytea - a string of hex bytes.

Comment: This actually worked neatly, but in my case non-ASCII letters appeared in Arial until clicked (the font used in forms was Helvetica). But at least they appeared, so after changing the default font it seems your solution works like charm. Thanks!

Comment: This is not working for me, and apparently this is an ongoing issue with several complexities.

Answer (score 4):

The underlying reason form fields are not showing up after being filled in, is that the values are not being added to the stream. Adding "NeedAppearances" tells the PDF reader that it needs to update the appearance, in this case it needs to create a stream for each field value, but not all PDF readers will honor that, and the fields may still look blank or have the default values.

The best solution to make sure the fields are updated for any reader is to create a stream for each field and add it to the field's XObject.

Here is an example solution for single line text fields. It also encodes the stream, updates the default value, and sets the fields to read only, which are all optional.

```py
# Example data.
data = {
    "field_name": "some value"
}

# Get template.
template = PdfReader("template-form.pdf", strict=False)

# Initialize writer.
writer = PdfWriter()

# Add the template page.
writer.add_page(template.pages[0])

# Get page annotations.
page_annotations = writer.pages[0][PageAttributes.ANNOTS]

# Loop through page annotations (fields).
for index in range(len(page_annotations)):  # type: ignore
    # Get annotation object.
    annotation = page_annotations[index].get_object()  # type: ignore

    # Get existing values needed to create the new stream and update the field.
    field = annotation.get(NameObject("/T"))
    new_value = data.get(field, 'N/A')
    ap = annotation.get(AnnotationDictionaryAttributes.AP)
    x_object = ap.get(NameObject("/N")).get_object()
    font = annotation.get(InteractiveFormDictEntries.DA)
    rect = annotation.get(AnnotationDictionaryAttributes.Rect)

    # Calculate the text position.
    font_size = float(font.split(" ")[1])
    w = round(float(rect[2] - rect[0] - 2), 2)
    h = round(float(rect[3] - rect[1] - 2), 2)
    text_position_h = h / 2 - font_size / 3  # approximation

    # Create a new XObject stream.
    new_stream = f'''
        /Tx BMC 
        q
        1 1 {w} {h} re W n
        BT
        {font}
        2 {text_position_h} Td
        ({new_value}) Tj
        ET
        Q
        EMC
    '''

    # Add Filter type to XObject.
    x_object.update(
        {
            NameObject(StreamAttributes.FILTER): NameObject(FilterTypes.FLATE_DECODE)
        }
    )

    # Update and encode XObject stream.
    x_object._data = FlateDecode.encode(encode_pdfdocencoding(new_stream))

    # Update annotation dictionary.
    annotation.update(
        {
            # Update Value.
            NameObject(FieldDictionaryAttributes.V): TextStringObject(
                new_value
            ),
            # Update Default Value.
            NameObject(FieldDictionaryAttributes.DV): TextStringObject(
                new_value
            ),
            # Set Read Only flag.
            NameObject(FieldDictionaryAttributes.Ff): NumberObject(
                FieldFlag(1)
            )
        }
    )

# Clone document root & metadata from template.
# This is required so that the document doesn't try to save before closing.
writer.clone_reader_document_root(template)

# write "output".
with open(f"output.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)  # type: ignore
```

Thanks to fidoriel and others from the discussion here: https://github.com/py-pdf/PyPDF2/issues/355.

Comment: What do you have in the encode_pdfdocencoding function?

Comment: @user353255 it's imported from PyPDF2.generic.

Comment: Where is the FlateDecode class imported from?  (I'm using pypdf 3.17.4) - didn't find it anywhere in pypdf.  Also, could you list all of the imports that are needed here?  Some were fairly difficult to track down on the internets: from pypdf.constants import AnnotationDictionaryAttributes,InteractiveFormDictEntries,PageAttributes,StreamAttributes,FilterTypes

Comment: found it, in pypdf.filters.  And more classes from pypdf.generic (FieldDictionaryAttributes, FieldFlag).

Comment: After getting the various imports in place, the code throws an exception on the writer.clone_reader_document_root(template) line, going down into _writer.py, line 284, get_object, IndexError: list index out of range.  Not sure if this is due to something about the template PDF I'm using, or, an issue in the pypdf code - will assume the former - any thoughts?

Comment: Even with the 'writer.clone_reader_document_root(template)' line commented out, it seems to work, in all but 'Reading Mode' in Acrobat Reader (on the phone) View Settings, which says 'Annotations are not allowed in Read mode.'  But, on the laptop, Acrobat Reader --> Menu --> View --> Read Mode, the field values do show up fine.  Anyway - great solution!  Still curious about the clone_reader_document_root error.

Comment: @TomGrundy This solution is in PyPDF2, so version 3 may need a different solution, but here are my imports:

from PyPDF2 import PdfReader, PdfWriter
from PyPDF2.constants import PageAttributes, FieldDictionaryAttributes, InteractiveFormDictEntries, \
    AnnotationDictionaryAttributes, StreamAttributes, FilterTypes
from PyPDF2.filters import FlateDecode
from PyPDF2.generic import NameObject, encode_pdfdocencoding, TextStringObject

Comment: @TomGrundy In the end, I ended up using PikePDF to flatten annotations, including form fields, into regular PDF content.

from pikepdf import Pdf
my_pdf = Pdf.open("path/to/form.pdf")
my_pdf.flatten_annotations('all')
my_pdf.save("path/to/flattened.pdf")

Comment: Thanks for responding - I wasn't aware of pyqpdf.  All of your code works in pypdf 3.17.4, which is nice - except for the clone_reader_document_root line, which is probably for a different reason.  Regardless, this gets us up and running after a lot of searching, so, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

This is what works for me on Python 3.8 and PyPDF4 (but I think it will work as well with PyPDF2):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PyPDF4.generic import NameObject
from PyPDF4.generic import TextStringObject
from PyPDF4.pdf import PdfFileReader
from PyPDF4.pdf import PdfFileWriter

import random
import sys

reader = PdfFileReader(sys.argv[1])

writer = PdfFileWriter()
# Try to "clone" the original one (note the library has cloneDocumentFromReader)
# but the render pdf is blank.
writer.appendPagesFromReader(reader)
writer._info = reader.trailer["/Info"]
reader_trailer = reader.trailer["/Root"]
writer._root_object.update(
    {
        key: reader_trailer[key]
        for key in reader_trailer
        if key in ("/AcroForm", "/Lang", "/MarkInfo")
    }
)

page = writer.getPage(0)

params = {"Foo": "Bar"}

# Inspired by updatePageFormFieldValues but also handles checkboxes.
for annot in page["/Annots"]:
    writer_annot = annot.getObject()
    field = writer_annot["/T"]
    if writer_annot["/FT"] == "/Btn":
        value = params.get(field, random.getrandbits(1))
        if value:
            writer_annot.update(
                {
                    NameObject("/AS"): NameObject("/On"),
                    NameObject("/V"): NameObject("/On"),
                }
            )
    elif writer_annot["/FT"] == "/Tx":
        value = params.get(field, field)
        writer_annot.update(
            {
                NameObject("/V"): TextStringObject(value),
            }
        )

with open(sys.argv[2], "wb") as f:
    writer.write(f)
```

This updates text fields and checkboxes.

I believe the key part is copying some parts from the original file:

```py
reader_trailer = reader.trailer["/Root"]
writer._root_object.update(
    {
        key: reader_trailer[key]
        for key in reader_trailer
        if key in ("/AcroForm", "/Lang", "/MarkInfo")
    }
)
```

Note: Please feel free to share this solution in other places. I consulted a lot of SO questions related to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to reopen with `pdfrw`

The following has worked for me for Adobe Reader, Acrobat, Skim, and Mac OS Preview:

```
pip install pdfrw
```

```
import pdfrw

pdf = pdfrw.PdfReader("<input_name>")
for page in pdf.pages:
    annotations = page.get("/Annots")
    if annotations:
        for annotation in annotations:
            annotation.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(AP=""))
                        
pdf.Root.AcroForm.update(pdfrw.PdfDict(NeedAppearances=pdfrw.PdfObject('true')))
pdfrw.PdfWriter().write("<output_name>", pdf)
```

Answer (score 0):

alepisa's answer was the closest to working for me (thank you, alepisa), but I just had to change one small section

```
  elif writer_annot["/FT"] == "/Tx":
    value = params.get(field, field)
    writer_annot.update(
```

This was producing an output where my PDF had the desired fields updated based off the dictionary with field names and values I passed it, but every fillable field, whether I wanted them filled or not, was populated with the name of that fillable field. I changed the elif statement to the one below and everything worked like a charm!

```
elif writer_annot["/FT"] == "/Tx":
    field_value = field_values.get(field_name, "")
    writer_annot.update({NameObject("/V"): TextStringObject(field_value),
                        #This line below is just for formatting
                        NameObject("/DA"): TextStringObject("/Helv 0 Tf 0 g")})
```

This nested back into the rest of alepisa's script should work for anybody having issues with getting the output in Acrobat to show the values without clicking on the cell!