# Python - How to properly fill a multiline text field in PDF form using pdfrw?

Tags: python, pdf, acrobat, pdf-form, pdfrw

I'm filling a PDF form using python with pdfrw. I have no problem with any single line text field in the form. But when I try to fill a multi-line textfield it doesn`t render properly, it ignores break lines.

This is part of my code:

```
pdf.Root.AcroForm.update(PdfDict(NeedAppearances=PdfObject('true')))

for x in range(0, len(pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields)):
    try:
        if pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields[x].T in ['(Observaciones)']:
            pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields[x].update(PdfDict(V='This\nis\nmultiline', Ff=1))
            continue
```

This is the output.

[image]

This is the settings in the form field using Adobe Acrobat.

[image]

I have selected the options: Multiline, Scroll Long Text, Allow Rich Text Formatting.

I have tried using `\r` and the `<br>` tag too.

How should I set the value to render properly?

Comment: Uncheck "Permitir formato de texto enriquecido" (Allow Rich Text Formatting), and use \r (or \n) as line break. Note that Richt Text Formatting uses the richValue property, which has a rather complex structure.

Comment: I unchecked this option, tried \r (and \n) but it didn't changed the result. Text still in single line.

Comment: Do you by chance have any Format settings active?

Comment: No, it doesn't, it is set to None. Should I select any of the others?

Comment: No; my suspicion was that there was a format preventing the proper multiline display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After struggling with flattening my fields (setting to read-only) while keeping the multiline intact I finally found the solution.

I came across this rushed solution to just turn the ‘**/Ff**’ value to 1 but in doing so you run the chance of removing some of the formatting for the form, and here is a better explanation on how to manipulate this field.

In the [‘PDF Reference: third edition’](https://opensource.adobe.com/dc-acrobat-sdk-docs/pdfstandards/pdfreference1.4.pdf) *page:552* it states

> “The value of the field dictionary’s Ff entry is an unsigned 32-bit
> integer containing flags specifying various characteristics of the
> field. Bit positions within the flag word are numbered from 1
> (low-order) to 32 (high-order).“

So, when I looked into the Ff field I got 4096 (in binary = 0001-0000-0000-0000) for allot of the forms I was struggling with. Turns out that the 13th bit controls the multiline setting and just setting the **Ff** to 1 therefor erases the rest of the settings and only dictates that the specific form should be read-only.

You could just do it the lazy way and give **Ff** the value 4097 (or whatever your Ff value is +1) or flip the bit you want in the byte string that you want to manipulate.

Here is a simple way to do it, that is modifiable to your needs.

```
bitPosition = 0 #First position being value 0
bitValue = 1
mask = 1 << bitPosition
oldFfValue = pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields[x].Ff
newFfValue = (int(oldFfValue) & ~mask) | ((1 << 0) & mask)
pdf.Root.AcroForm.Fields[x].Ff.update(PdfDict(Ff=newFfValue))
```

ps. Not 100% sure if accessing the **Ff** value works this way for you since my approach was based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279950/how-to-edit-editable-pdf-using-the-pdfrw-library) persons example code since it fit my needs better.

All in all I recommend giving the PDF reference document a look if you want to mess with the rest of the bits to see the interesting characteristics they control.

Other usefull bits are for example:

- 14th bit is for password star typing.
- 23rd bit is for disabling spell-check.
- 24th bit is for disabling scrolling of the field.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue too. I haven't delved into the implementation of the multi-line feature by pdfrw, but I do know that when I flatten the form field (Ff=1, which you also have in your code), it no longer supports multi-line. Try taking that off and see if multi-line is supported again.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot read Spanish setting, but if you make sure these 2 fields are checked, then you probably will be OK.

[Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ec7vJ.png)

Comment: As I wrote at the bottom of the image, I already checked those two options.

Answer (score 0):

I set the the `ff` to `4097` and it seems to be working but need to check if it has impact on other things.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).