# Unable to install Poppler on Windows using Conda

Tags: python, poppler

I've been trying to install Poppler to use pdf2image to do some pdf to jpeg conversions using Anaconda Prompt.

I tried running this:
conda install -c conda-forge poppler

However, it gets stuck on "Solving Environment" and nothing really happens.

I tried another way but it gave the following error:

```
(base) C:\Users\taman>conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 poppler
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from 
current channels:

  - poppler

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf201901/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/label/cf201901/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After trying several methods, ultimately what worked is given on this link:
https://github.com/QISKit/qiskit-terra/issues/586

I had to manually download the library, unlock the zip folder using a 7-zip software and add the bin address to the environment variable path.

Answer (score -1):

Poppler on windows

- Download miniconda for Windows 32/64 bit from
  https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html
- Install poppler for windows using command:

  ```
  conda install -c conda-forge poppler
                  or
  conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 poppler
                   or
  conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 poppler
  ```

Comment: The OP said they tried `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` and it got stuck. Your primary answer is to try `conda install -c conda-forge poppler` . In terms of the question, ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), your answer could be improved upon.